# How to cancel a request using OKHttp library?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am requesting information of a file using `OKHttp` library like this:

```
    final String url = "my_url";
    final String tag = "tag";
    final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(url)
                        .get()
                        .tag(tag)
                        .build();
                Call call = client.newCall(request);
                Response response = call.execute();
                //work with response object, etc.
            } catch (IOException  e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
```

And to cancel Request I use this code as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46477662/6940373) says:

```
    for (Call call : mHttpClient.dispatcher().queuedCalls()) {
        if (call.request().tag().equals("tag"))
            call.cancel();
    }

    for (Call call : mHttpClient.dispatcher().runningCalls()) {
        if (call.request().tag().equals("tag"))
            call.cancel();
    }
```

But the size of `runningCalls` list and `queuedCalls` list is zero. why? How can i cancel a request in OKHttp? Thanks.

Comment: Use `enqueue()` instead of `execute()` and remove your thread (as OkHttp will handle the threading for you). Hold onto your `Call` object. Call `cancel()` on it if the work needs to be canceled before your callback gets invoked.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to request information of the file inside my own thread. I think the only way to cancel a request in my example is holding Call object then calling cancel() on it. right?

Comment: "I need to request information of the file inside my own thread" -- why do you think this? "I think the only way to cancel a request in my example is holding Call object then calling cancel() on it. right?" -- yes, ideally wrapped in an `AtomicReference` or otherwise synchronized (since you will be trying to work with that field or variable in multiple threads).